# bindLabel and bindValue chosen-multiple in Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, jquery-chosen, angular-chosen

I am facing an issue when using angular-chosen plugin in my app.

```
<select class="form-control chosen-rtl" id="userList" ng-model="ssc.selectedUser" chosen multiple search-contains="true"
          placeholder-text-multiple=" ' ' " no-results-text=" ' ' " ng-options="user.username as user.nameAr for user in ssc.userList">
          <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

I am displaying the list of usernames in dropdown. When user selects an option it should tag its id (user.nameAr) not dropdown label which is userName. Can anybody help me in finding a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Just simply do this:

```
<select class="form-control chosen-rtl" id="userList" ng-model="ssc.selectedUser" chosen multiple search-contains="true"
      placeholder-text-multiple=" ' ' " no-results-text=" ' ' " ng-options="user.nameAr as user.username for user in ssc.userList">
      <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

With this user.username will be displayed in the options and on selection user.nameAr will bind to the ng-model.

Comment: Nope.. With your code even dropdown item has changed to  user.nameA , which i don't want. I can bind the value to model thats not an issue here.. but when i select label it get selected as label